# Can't to connect to postgres container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I define `postgres` server in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    expose:
        - 5432
```

Then in another docker container I tried to connect to this postgres container. But it gives an error with warning:

```
Is the server running on host "db" (172.22.0.2) and accepting
data-service_1  |   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Why container can't to connect to another by provided information (`host`="db" and `port`=`5432`)?

PS
Full `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"
services:
    data-service:
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
          - "50051:50051"
    db:
        image: postgres:9.5
        depends_on:
            - data-volume
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=cobrain
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=a
            - POSTGRES_DB=datasets
        ports:
          - "8000:5432"
        expose:
            - 5432
        volumes_from:
            - data-volume
            # - container:postgres9.5-data
        restart: always

    data-volume:
        image: busybox
        command: echo "I'm data container"
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: please post full `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @AlexKarshin I added it.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution #1. Same file.**

To be able to access the `db` container, you have to define your other containers in context of `docker-compose.yml`. When containers are started, each container gets all other containers mapped in `/etc/hosts`.

Just do

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: your/image
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
```

If you do not wish to put your other containers into the same `docker-compose.yml`, there are other solutions:

**Solution #2. IP**

Do `docker inspect <name of your db container>` and look for `IPAddress` directive in the result listing. Use that `IPAddress` as host to connect to.

**Solution #3. Networks**

Make your containers join same network. For that, under each service, define:

```
services:
  db:
    networks:
     - myNetwork
```

Don't forget to change `db` for each container you are starting.

I usually go with the first solution during development. I use `apache+php` as one container and `pgsql` as another one, a separate DB for every project.  I do not start more than one setting of `docker-compose.yml`, so in this case defining both containers in one `.yml` config is perfect.

Comment: But `build: .` is the same as `image: your/image`. I can't see difference between solution 1 and mine one.

Comment: actually, on closer inspection, I think `depends_on` might give you problems, because you are defining a recursive dependency

Comment: recursive? No, it's just a chain of dependencies `data-service --> db --> data-volume`.

Comment: ah, yes, sorry, it's naming getting mixed up :) I will delete my answer and will try to come up with the right solution

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich what happens if you define `expose` as string? I.e. `- "5432"`? All docs define it as string.

Comment: Okay, let's try something else... Can you post here in the comments the output of `docker exec -i data-service_1 cat /etc/hosts`? Instead of `data-service_1` put the name of your data service container.

Answer (score -1):

the depends on is not correct. i would try to use other paramters like LINKS and environment:

```
version: "2"
    services:
        data-service:
            build: .
            links:
                - db
            ports:
              - "50051:50051"
            volumes_from: ["db"]
            environment:
                DATABASE_HOST: db
        db:
            image: postgres:9.5
            environment:
                - POSTGRES_USER=cobrain
                - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=a
                - POSTGRES_DB=datasets
            ports:
              - "8000:5432"
            expose:
                - 5432
            #volumes_from:
                #- data-volume
                # - container:postgres9.5-data
            restart: always

        data-volume:
            image: busybox
            command: echo "I'm data container"
            volumes:
                - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

this one works for me (not postgres but mysql)

Comment: `depends_on` has nothing to do with getting containers communicate with each other..